# Accessing ConfigurationManager.AppSettings value from Spring.NET xml configuration

Tags: .net, configuration, connection-string, spring.net, configurationmanager

I have a requirement that requires me to use Spring.net to get a connectionstring that is stored inside the app.config, and then inject the retrieved connectionstring to a instantiated object.

How can I do this using Spring.net's xml configuration?

For e.g., instead of my codes doing this:

```xml
// Spring.net config:
<object name="myService" type="com.acme.MyService, com.acme">
    <constructor-arg type="System.String" value="myConnectionName"/>
</object>

// Web.config:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionName" connectionString="DB_connectionstring"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

```cs
// Codes:
public class MyService {
    public MyService(string connectionName) {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionName];
        // use connectionString to create a DB connection, etc
    }
}
```

I want it like this:

```xml
 // Spring.net config:
<object name="myService" type="com.acme.MyService, com.acme">
    <constructor-arg type="System.String" ref="retrievedConnectionString"/>
</object>    
// How to make a call similar to "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionName]" and get the connection string from Web.config and put inside "retrievedConnectionString"?

// Web.config:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionName" connectionString="DB_connectionstring"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

```cs
// Codes:
public class MyService {
    public MyService(string connectionString) {
        // use connectionString to create a DB connection, etc
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to call `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[..]` from Spring.net xml config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past I used an [expression](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html) to achieve this, but through this question and bbaia's answer, I found out that a better way to do this is using a `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer`. When you use a `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer` instead of my "expression-hack", you don't tie yourself to the `appSettings / connectionStrings` style configuration of your variables: you can switch to one of the [`VariableSources`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource) provided by spring.net or even implement your own `IVariableSource`.

Out-of-the-box, Spring.NET provides `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer`s to retrieve variables from standard .NET settings like `AppSettings`, `ConnectionStrings`, `UserSettings` and `ApplicationSettings`. This is partially illustrated by bbaia's answer and you'll find a complete example below.

#### "Expression hack": calling `ConfigurationManager` from xml config

So, I don't advice you to use this, but this is the hack I used in the past, applied to your configuration:

```xml
<object object name="myService" type="com.acme.MyService, com.acme">
  <constructor-arg name="Connection" 
                   expression="T(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager).ConnectionStrings['myConnectionName']" />
</object>
```

You can use this same approach for `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, e.g.:

```
<object object name="myService" type="com.acme.MyService, com.acme">
  <constructor-arg name="AnotherConstructorArgument" 
                   expression="T(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager).AppSettings['mySetting']" />
</object>
```

#### `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer`: reference .NET settings from Spring.NET xml config

You can easily configure a `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer` to retrieve variables from standard .NET settings like `AppSettings`, `ConnectionStrings`, `UserSettings` and `ApplicationSettings`. For instance, consider this xml configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" >

  <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
    <property name="VariableSources">
      <list>
        <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ConnectionStringsVariableSource, Spring.Core" />
        <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ConfigSectionVariableSource, Spring.Core">
          <!-- Sections to read, sepearated by comma (leave out spaces) -->
          <property name="SectionNames"
                    value="appSettings,applicationSettings/q7991262.Properties.Settings,userSettings/q7991262.Properties.Settings" />
        </object>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

  <!-- Note that you have to append '.connectionstring' to the key! -->
  <object id="usingConnectionStringsVariableSource" 
          type="q7991262.MyService, q7991262">
    <property name="Connection" 
              value="${myConnectionName.connectionString}" />
  </object>

  <object id="configSectionVariableSource" 
          type="q7991262.MyService, q7991262">
    <property name="Connection" 
              value="${myConnectionNameAppSettings}" />
  </object>

  <object id="userSettingsSection" 
          type="q7991262.MyService, q7991262">
    <property name="Connection" 
              value="${myConectionNameUserSetting}" />
  </object>

  <object id="applicationSetting" 
          type="q7991262.MyService, q7991262">
    <property name="Connection" 
              value="${myConectionNameApplicationSetting}" />
  </object>

</objects>
```

It reads the settings from this `app.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="q7991262.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="q7991262.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionName" 
         connectionString="From connection string section."/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="myConnectionNameAppSettings" 
         value="From app setting section." />
  </appSettings>

  <userSettings>
    <q7991262.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="myConectionNameUserSetting" serializeAs="String">
        <value>My connection from user settings.</value>
      </setting>
    </q7991262.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>

  <applicationSettings>
    <q7991262.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="myConectionNameApplicationSetting" serializeAs="String">
        <value>My connection from application settings.</value>
      </setting>
    </q7991262.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

</configuration>
```

These configurations are taken from [this working sample at github](https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/tree/master/spring-questions/q7991262-accessing-configurationmanager).

Comment: ref: https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/blob/master/spring-questions/q7991262-accessing-configurationmanager/objects.xml

Comment: I mark this as the answer because it gave the examples to retrieve values from both appSettings and connectionStrings, which is what I exactly want.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the VariablePlaceholderConfigurer :
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource

The ConnectionStringsVariableSource implementation allows you to get the value from the ConnectionString section in your config file.

```
<object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
  <property name="VariableSources">
    <list>
      <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ConnectionStringsVariableSource, Spring.Core"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</object>

<object name="myService" type="com.acme.MyService, com.acme">
    <constructor-arg type="System.String" value="${myConnectionName.connectionString}"/>
</object>
```

Example from the Spring.NET forum:
http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?3961

Comment: Was just about to add this one too, but it didn't work in my case because I forgot to add `.connectionString` to the name, which is required by the `ConnectionStringsVariableSource`. You can get the provider name using `value="${myConnectionName.providerName}"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, IVariableSource implementations are not documented. You have to dig into the code like you did.