# VariablePlaceholderConfigurer depending on Build Profile

Tags: c#, spring, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, spring.net

We are using a `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer` for defining e.g. the db-connection, ...

```
<object name="appConfigPropertyHolder"
      type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
<property name="VariableSources">
  <list>
    <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyFileVariableSource, Spring.Core">
      <property name="Location"
                value="~\Config\Spring.Properties.config" />
    </object>
  </list>
</property>
</object>       

<db:provider id="projectCockpitDbProvider"
           provider="${dbProvider}"
           connectionString="${dbConnectionString}" />
```

Is there a way to define the properties-file depending on the build profile?

Something like

```
<property name="Location" 
          value="~\Config\Spring.Properties.{$BuildProfile}.config" />
```

or

```
<property name="Location" condition="[Buildprofile]"
          value="~\Config\Spring.Properties.config" />
```

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: You could use the `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer` `Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ConfigSectionVariableSource` as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991262/accessing-configurationmanager-appsettings-value-from-spring-net-xml-configurati and a debug/release web.config http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx